# React hydration error when using Apollo Client `useQuery` (Next JS)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, apollo-client

Specifically the `loading` state in my case. During SSR loading is `false` and during CSR loading is `true` in the initial render. I show loading UI based on this state so the HTML in server and client is different. I can use a `useEffect` and `useLazyQuery` to workaround this but it seems like there has to be a better way.

```js
// server renders component and client renders "Loading" on initial render
// which throws the hydration error
function Page () {
    const {data, loading} = useQuery(query)
    
    if(loading) {
        return "Loading"
    }

    return <Component data={data} />
}
```

```
@apollo/client : 3.3.19
next: 12.1.6 (pages router)
```

Comment: You need to give a bit more information - are you using the App Router, or the Pages router? How do you do the SSR? Which versions of Apollo Client? If you use the app router, do you use the Apollo Client package for Next.js?

Comment: @phry Added the info you mentioned. I don't think it matters if it's app router or pages router, the apollo client package's behaviour probably doesn't change (My app use pages router). SSR using `getStaticProps`.

Comment: You need a separate package for comapatibility between the App router and Apollo Client, so it matters very much :)

Comment: As for the case at hand - the Apollo Client version you are using is about three years old - the current version of AC is 3.8.6. You might be encountering a bug that might have been fixed since, so my first advice would be to update and see if that fixes your problems.